# optimoptions tolfun using matlab back to default

Tags: matlab

I altered tolfun to 1e-10, however when running lsqcurvefit tolfun is restored back to default. Anyone knowing what's done wrong?

```
if LMAlgorithm
    options = optimoptions(...
        @lsqcurvefit, 'levenberg-marquardt', .001, ...
        'Tolfun', 1e-10);
end

[personalParams,personalRes,personalResidual] = lsqcurvefit(...
    heightModel,initialValues,personalData(:,1),personalData(:,2),[],[],options);
```

Comment: What makes you think it reverts back to default value?

Comment: Are you sure `LMAlgorithm` is `true`?

Comment: Optimization stopped because the relative sum of squares (r) is changing
by less than options.TolFun = 1.000000e-06. is what I find if i look at stopping criteria details.

Comment: @user2694285: Just print the contents of `options` prior to the call to `lsqcurvefit`. What is the value of `TolFun`?

Comment: how do i print these contents? display-iter in options?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps 'Tolfun' should instead be 'TolFun'?